# Proper approach to dealing with intermittent errors and Observables

Tags: c#, observable, system.reactive

I am using the GraphQL.NET client to subscribe to data on a remote service. The client returns an Observable so when the subscription is created you, as expected, receive new messages in `onNext` and get errors (both initial connection errors, reconnection errors, and anything else) in `onError`. The GraphQL client has the ability to **automatically** reconnect if the initial connection fails or when an established connection drops.

I know that by convention, any messages coming in on `onError` is *supposed* to terminate the sequence of messages. However, *somehow* they are able to continue sending to `onNext` and `onError` after that first `onError`. I have tried reading through the code but it is confusing. There seems to be multiple nesting of `Observable` and I *suspect* they are creating a **new** sequence when they encounter an error.

To clarify my issue, **suppose** I had the following pseudo `Event` based wrapper class.

```
public class PubSubSubscription() {
   ...
   public void CreateSubscription<TResponse>(string topic) {
      // GraphQL client
      var stream = client 
  .CreateSubscriptionStream<FixConnectionChangedSubscriptionResult>(...);

      stream
         .Subscribe(
            response => {
               // Do stuff with incoming data (validation, mapping, logging, etc.)

               // send it on the UI
               DataReceived?.Invoke(this, new DataReceivedEventArgs { Message = response });
            },
            ex => {
               // ******************************
               // Note that the Observable created by CreateSubscriptionStream()
               // will call `onError` over-and-over since it _seems_ like it is
               // creating (and re-creating) nested Observables in its own
               // classes. In the event of an initial connection failure or
               // re-connect it will raise an error and then automatically
               // try again.
               // ******************************

               // send it on to UI
               ErrorDetected?.Invoke(this, new ErrorDetectedEventArgs { Exception = ex });
            });
   }
   ...
}
```

I would then call it as follows (or close enough)...

```
...
var orders = ordersPubSub.CreateSubscription("/orders");

orders.DataReceived += OnDataReceived;
orders.ErrorDetected += OnErrorDetected;

void OnErrorDetected(object sender, ErrorDetectedEventArgs e) {
   // Can be called multiple times
   
   // Display message in UI
}
...
```

I am having trouble converting that event-based wrapper approach to an Observable wrapper approach.

```
public class PubSubSubscription() {
   ...
   public IObservable<TResponse> CreateSubscription<TResponse>(string topic) {
      // Observable that I give back to my UI
      var eventSubject = new Subject<TResponse>();

      // GraphQL client
      var stream = client
      .CreateSubscriptionStream<FixConnectionChangedSubscriptionResult>(...);

      stream
         .Subscribe(
            response => {
               // Do stuff with incoming data (validation, mapping, logging, etc.)

               // send it on the UI
               eventSubject.onNext(response);
            },
            ex => {
               // ******************************
               // Note that the Observable created by CreateSubscriptionStream()
               // will call `onError` over-and-over since it _seems_ like it is
               // creating (and re-creating) nested Observables in its own
               // classes. In the event of an initial connection failure or
               // re-connect it will raise an error and then automatically
               // try again.
               // ******************************

               // send it on to UI
               eventSubject.onError(ex);
            });

      return eventSubject.AsObservable();
   }
   ...
}
```

This I would then call it as follows (or close enough)...

```
...
var orders = ordersPubSub.CreateSubscription("/orders");

orders
   // Things I have tried...

   // Do() by itself does not stop the exception from hitting onError (which makes sense)
   .Do(
      _ => { },
      ex => // display in UI)
   // Retry() seems to cause the GraphQL subscription to "go away" because I no longer see connection attempts
   .Retry()
   // Stops the exception from hitting onError but the sequence still stops since I need to return _something_ from this method
   .Catch(() => {
      // display in UI
      
      return Observable.Empty<T>();  
   })
   .Subscribe(
      msg => // do something with data,
      ex => // display in UI);
}
...
```

Bottom line is what is the proper approach to dealing with sequences that can be "temporarily interrupted"?

I am also unsure of the idea of pushing the responsibility of retries onto the **observer**. This means that I would need to duplicate the logic each time `CreateSubscription()` is called. Yet, if I move it **into** the `CreateSubscription()` method, I am still unsure how to let the observer know the interruption happened so the UI can be updated.

One approach I am playing with (after reading about it as a possible solution) is to wrap my `TResponse` in a "fake" `SubscriptionResponse<TResponse>` which has `T Value` and `Exception Error` properties so the outer Observable only has `onNext` called. Then in my `Subscribe` I add `if/else` logic to check if `Error` is non-null and react accordingly. But this just feels ugly... I would almost want to go back to using events...

Comment: Are you looking for the `Retry()` operator? Having a `OnError` event will end the subscription by definition, anything else would be confusing and unexpected.

Comment: I had already looked at `Retry()` (in conjunction with `Do()` so I can notify users of that intermittent failure) but it did not work well. The inner GraphQL client already does its own retry logic (with back-off) which adds increasing delays to further attempts. Yet when I added `Retrty()` I saw the `Do()` firing non-stop without any delay. My _guess_ is that it recreated the outer subscription without the GraphQL client being recreated (which I do not think I want anyways). Will update original post to clarify usage.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an unruly observable - one that produces multiple errors without ended - you can make it workable by doing this:

```
IObservable<int> unruly = ...;

IObservable<Notification<int>> workable =
    unruly
        .Materialize();
```

The `Materialize` operator turns the `IObservable<int>` into an `IObservable<Notification<int>>` where the `OnCompleted`, `OnError`, and `OnNext` messages all get converted to `OnNext` messages that you can inspect like this:

[image: screenshot]

Now you can deal with the errors without the sequence ending. When you've cleared them you can restore the sequence with `Dematerialize` like so:

```
IObservable<int> ruly =
    workable
        .Where(x => x.Kind != NotificationKind.OnError)
        .Dematerialize();
```

Comment: Interesting. I will check this out to see if it helps. Will report back my findings. Thank you. That being said, I think my question still stands -- in summary "given an object that can raise one event for data (multiple times) and **another** event for errors (*multiple times**), how would you convert that class to use `Observables` instead of events? How would you architect the replacement of the error event?"

Comment: @Jason - I would consider errors values in their own right and not an error in the observable pipeline. So either two observables, like there are two events, or one observable capable of producing a discriminated union object (like `Notification<T>` in my answer).